# are hdl arrays left to right or right to left?

Tags: indexing, logic, hdl, nand2tetris

I have sel = in[2]. lets say sel is 01, would sel[0] = 0 or 1, I am confused if its left to right or right to left.

this is for the nand2tetris course and right now I am using left to right as 0-i, please if someone can clarify I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you have defined your array

```
signal right_to_left : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := 0b11110000; 
# right_to_left [0] = 0

signal left_to_right: std_logic_vector(0 to 7) := 0b11110000; 
# left_to_right[0] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, NAND2Tetris uses the convention that the rightmost bit is the least-significant one. You can confirm this by checking the course materials related to decoding the instruction set, since that references bit positions in a 16-bit bus.